# Long Term Debt Due

Tags: stocks, debt, balance-sheet

[image]

I would like to see the *Long Term Debt Due*, but it seems it is not displayed. The image above shows the current and long-term liabilities of META. Is this expense included in one of the categories in the photo? For me, if the debt due in the year increases from year to year compared to its long term debts, then it is not necessarily a good thing

Comment: Have you checked META's Form 10-K filings?

Comment: Yes, but it is not disclosed

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Are you looking for the portion of long term debt that is due within 12 months? Could you provide a link to the Form 10-K you looked at?

Comment: "Is this expense included in one of the categories in the photo?" — What expense are you referring to?

Comment: @Flux Yes, it is the portion of the long term debt is due within 12 months

Comment: @Flux https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=1431959&accession_number=0000950170-22-002601&xbrl_type=v# Even in the SEC filings, it is not mentioned

Comment: Where did you get the data shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Is your question about Meta Platforms, Inc. (Nasdaq: META), or about Meta Materials Inc. (Nasdaq: MMAT)? The SEC filing you linked to is for Meta Materials Inc.

Comment: I am talking about META NASDAQ

Comment: Meta Platforms, Inc. had no long term debt, so it does not have any long term debt due within 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

If a debt is due within 12 months it is no longer a long-term debt. Bonds or other debts that are due within the next year are reported as "current" liabilities. Probably under "Current portions of LT Debt"

Comment: It is unclear what company the OP is referring to. In the comments, the OP gave a link to Meta Materials Inc. (MMAT) filings, which does not seem to match the data shown in the OP's screenshot. If the OP instead refers to Meta Platforms, Inc. (META), then it has no long term debt due within the 12 months because it had no long term debt.